# Commonness of active relative clauses vs. passive relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

I wrote:

> I have a dependency treebank including 100 structures, **which I divide into a training set and a test set.**

Should I say *which I divide it into ....*? or
*that I divide it into...*?

cause in its current form sounds weird to my ears! I used to passive relative clauses like "which is divided into...", then using an active relative clause was a bit weird!! are they common as passive relative clauses?!

for example was it better to rephrase it as ...

"*... which is divided into ....*"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, except that both occurrences of "set" should be plural.

Comment: No, because _a dependency treebank..._ is the object of the relative clause: _I divide a dependency treebank ... into ...._ Inserting "it" would mean there are two objects which is not possible. Yes, you can rephrase it the way you suggest.

Comment: After your edit, both "which I divide(d)" and "which is divided" are correct. However using the passive clause omits the detail that you were the one to divide them. If this last bit is irrelevant, the passive form is preferable. Also, since you only have only two sets, you might consider "split" or "separated" instead of divided.

Comment: @MorganFR part of its weirdness was because of present tense, *which I divided* sounds better

Comment: Please understand that you can't insert "it".

Comment: @BillJ I know! just wanted to get sure, how about *that I divided it...*?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The relative clause can only have one object and that has been taken with _dependency treebank ...._ You can say _that/which I divide into a training set ..._ or the passive _that/which is divided into a training set ..._

Comment: Does **including** mean "comprised of" there? And are those 100 structures split between a training set and a test set?

Comment: @TRomano exactly

Comment: A tree bank with 100 structures which are divided into two sets, one for training, the other for testing.  I'd go with the passive here, **which are divided**.

Answer (score -1):

No, relative pronouns (such as "which") can function as subject or object of the relative clause. Both your active and passive examples are fine.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the title of a question a bit, please consider that in you answer too.

Comment: What about "*... that I divided it into...*? is it grammatical?

Comment: @Ahmad No, it is not grammatical. The relative *which* **replaces** *it* in your sentence; *which* has to point forward to a "gap", to something missing in the following clause. When you leave *it* in place there is no gap, and the reader is puzzled to know what role *which* plays.